# How to read values of all keys in a json object and add it to state?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the following JSON and reading it to state as -

```
this.state = {filterAttributes: MYResult.ParametricList_Filter_Attributes || []}

{
    "ParametricList_Attributes": [
                ....
        ....
        ....
    ],
    "ParametricList_Filter_Attributes": [
        {
            "PartNumber": "Part Number",
            "ProductLine": "Product Line"
        }
    ],
    "Products": [
                ....
        ....
        ....
    ]
}
```

Now I wanted to have a constant which will have all the values of "ParametricList_Filter_Attributes".

In my below code, what I get in "attr" is `[object, object]`. How Can I get only values in the form of an array or List?

```
const filterAttrs = this.state.filterAttributes.map(attr => {
            console.log("attr --"+attr)


        });
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my below code, what I get in "attr" is `[object, object]`.

Only if you convert it to a string, as you did in that code. It's an object.

> How Can I get only values in the form of an array?

If you really want just the **values**, use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```
const filterAttrs = this.state.filterAttributes.map(attr => {
    console.log(Object.values(attr)); // ["Part Number", "Product Line"]
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    "ParametricList_Attributes": [
    /*
        ....
        ....
        ....
    */
    ],
    "ParametricList_Filter_Attributes": [
        {
            "PartNumber": "Part Number",
            "ProductLine": "Product Line"
        }
    ],
    "Products": [
    /*
        ....
        ....
        ....
    */
    ]
};
const filterAttrs = data.ParametricList_Filter_Attributes.map(attr => {
    console.log(Object.values(attr)); // ["Part Number", "Product Line"]
});
```

If you want the property keys and values, use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which gives you the key and value as an array:

```
const filterAttrs = this.state.filterAttributes.map(attr => {
    console.log(Object.entries(attr)); // [["PartNumber", "Part Number"], ["ProductLine", "Product Line"]]
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    "ParametricList_Attributes": [
    /*
        ....
        ....
        ....
    */
    ],
    "ParametricList_Filter_Attributes": [
        {
            "PartNumber": "Part Number",
            "ProductLine": "Product Line"
        }
    ],
    "Products": [
    /*
        ....
        ....
        ....
    */
    ]
};
const filterAttrs = data.ParametricList_Filter_Attributes.map(attr => {
    console.log(Object.entries(attr)); // [["PartNumber", "Part Number"], ["ProductLine", "Product Line"]]
});
```